# How to make a list view inside split view content responsible with full width?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have list of items showing in my view using list view,
First i implemented it without using split view, then it was responsive as well as list items was taking full width

```
   <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,20,20,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" 
               Name="ResultTextBlock" 
               FontSize="24" 
               Foreground="Red" 
               FontWeight="Bold" 
               Margin="20,20,0,0" />
    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Books}" 
              ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick" 
              IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BookListDataTemplate}">
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

This same list view i have move in to a splitview content, but this time the width got reduced and the content became non responsive.

```
   <Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BookListDataTemplate" x:DataType="data:Book">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Image Name="image" Source="{x:Bind CoverImage}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="150" />
            <StackPanel Margin="20,20,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="16" />
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Author}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="10" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <RelativePanel >

        <Button Name="hambergerbutton" FontSize="36" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;" Click="hambergerbutton_Click" ></Button>
        <StackPanel Background="Gray"></StackPanel>
        <TextBlock  RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                    RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True" 
                    FontSize="24">Books</TextBlock>

    </RelativePanel>


    <SplitView Grid.Row="1" Name="myspliview"
               DisplayMode="CompactInline"  OpenPaneLength="200" 
               CompactPaneLength="56" HorizontalAlignment="left">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <ListBox SelectionMode="single" Name="listicons" SelectionChanged="listicons_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xe72D;" FontSize="36" />
                        <TextBlock Text="share" FontSize="24" Margin="20,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xe724;" FontSize="36" />
                        <TextBlock Text="favourites" FontSize="24" Margin="20,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem></ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </SplitView.Pane>

        <SplitView.Content>
            <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,20,20,0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="100" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" 
               Name="ResultTextBlock" 
               FontSize="24" 
               Foreground="Red" 
               FontWeight="Bold" 
               Margin="20,20,0,0" />
                <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Books}" 
              ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick" 
              IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BookListDataTemplate}">
                </ListView>
            </Grid>



        </SplitView.Content>

    </SplitView>

</Grid>
```

[image]

i want the same ui inside split view content, and should be responsive, what i am doing wrong and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the *HorizontalAlignment* of your *SplitView* from **left** to **Stretch**.